# Secondary monitor won't display at full resolution with primary display disconnected

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, external-display, dell-latitude

The LCD display on my Dell E6500 notebook failed.  It had been working with a secondary monitor connected through a VGA cable at 1600x900 resolution until I removed the LCD from my notebook for repair.

Now the max resolution available on the secondary display is 1024x768.  If I reconnect the burned out primary display, the secondary monitor is again available at 1600x900.

The video card is an onboard Mobil Intel 4.

How can I maintain the secondary display at 1600x900 with the primary display disconnected (for repair)?

Edit:  I just noticed that when Windows boots, it displays at the correct resolution and I can see my desktop in all its glory for a couple seconds then reverts to 1024x768.

**Edit 2:** 
I appreciate the answers though they didn't apply to my particular problem.  To help anyone with this issue in the future, I ended up using a utility called PowerStrip and was able to force my external LCD to the correct resolution.  I can't account for why this occurred.  I have since repaired my original LCD, so the secondary displays correctly again without intervention.

Comment: Are you sure that the monitor can support that resolution? What model is the temporary LCD? Is the monitor showing up properly under device manager? There are a number of things missing to give you a definite answer :)

Comment: @laramie: You should've posted your edit as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the behavior you mentioned I think it has something to do with the driver or software configuration of the monitor (maybe "duplicate display" mode is active)

So 1)Could you try to change the display mode to secondary only (depending on your configuration that could be either from display properties or from control panel)

Or if it doesn't work 2)Try re-installing your display driver