# Entire display not fully visible on monitor all of a sudden?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, resolution, dvi

I'm using a monitor whose maximum resolution is 1440x900 and another monitor whose maximum resolution is 2048x1536. The first, is connected to an NVidia GT430 card. The second monitor is connected to the same card, but on a DVI port. I was using these two monitors as a dual monitor setup and both monitors were configured to maximum resolution and everything was fine.

Yesterday I disconnected both monitors and plugged in only the DVI port monitor and although the windows display properties showed me that I could configure it to maximum resolution, it was only until 1024x768 that I was able to see the taskbar. If I configured it to highest resolution, I had to move the mouse to the edges of the screen and the screen would scroll to show me the rest of the desktop (like how the screen scrolls in Age of Empires game). Even after I connected back the VGA port monitor and switched on the PC, the same problem persists. The VGA port monitor can be configured to max resolution, but the DVI port monitor will show the entire screen in one shot only until the 1024x768 resolution.

I haven't made any changes to the graphics settings or the graphics driver during this entire time. I don't understand why this is happening. I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/210023/secondary-monitor-wont-display-at-full-resolution-with-primary-display-disconne), but I feel it should be a simpler solution. Using Windows XP SP3 with an Intel motherboard (so Catalyst Control Center is not a solution for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What caused this problem was that one of the pins in either the DVI port of the graphics card or the DVI cable was not working. When I plugged in the monitor to a VGA port, everything worked fine.